# Not able to access file in Google Cloud Storage using Cloud Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

I am currently trying to read a pdf file that I have stored in my Google Cloud Storage bucket. I have finished writing my code using the Google Cloud Vision API to read pdf files, but for some reason when I try to access the file that I have stored, I receive an error in my code saying that permission was denied to the file. How can I fix this, and if needed what code should I include to fix this?

Comment: Please post your code how do you access the file in Cloud Storage Bucket and include the error message that you received when accessing the file.

Comment: Can you share the error message?